# Look up or insert new element to string list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So I want to have a function that takes a String and a list as an argument, and checks if that element is already on the list, if it is, returns the same list, if it isnt, adds it to the list and returns it, 'im a begginer with haskell so heres what I have tried with no sucess:

```
check:: String ->[String] ->[String]
check x [] = []++[x]
check x (y:xs) 
             | x==y = (y:xs)
             | otherwise = check x xs
```

Can someone point me the way ? thks

Comment: What is the problem you have with your code? Formulating the problem helps you as well as it helps us help you.

Comment: it wasnt workin, as it wasnt adding elements properly.. wonce's answer seems to work fine now !

Comment: I understand it wasn't working, but in *what way* wasn't it working? Did it give you an error message? Did it give you the result backwards? Did it print a Shakespearian insult? Did your computer explode? There are a lot of ways things can go wrong, and the first step in knowing why it went wrong is figuring out which way it actually went wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the existing function *elem* 
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem

```
check x ls
    | x `elem` ls = ls
    | otherwise   = (x:ls)
```

If you want to do it completely on your own for learning purpose, I suggest re-implementing *elem*.

Answer (score 2):

To implement `check`, we need to compare the elements of its second argument, `l`, one by one with its first argument, `x`. These elements of `l` that do not equal to `x` should be elements of the final result. If we find an element of `l` that equals `x`, there is no need to compare the rest of `l` with `x`.

So `check` can be implemented by using recursion like this

```
check x [] = [x]
check x l@(y:ys)
    | x == y    = l -- `l` is `y:ys`
    | otherwise = y : check x ys
```

Explanation:

1. If the second argument is empty list, then the result is `[x]`;
2. otherwise if the head of the second argument equals its first argument, the result should be the second argument;
3. finally, the head of its second argument should be part of the final result, and we should check the rest of its second argument recursively.